# Convert Json Object to string with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to convert this :

```
tags: [
    { tagName : "O365" },
    { tagName : "Skype for Business" }
]
```

to `"O365,Skype for Business"` as a string.

Could anyone help me to accomplish this using `Powershell` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: get-help ConvertFrom-Json

Answer (score 3):

Works only if you have only one "tags" property in your JSON :

```
$json = @"
{
    tags: [
        { tagName : "O365" },
        { tagName : "Skype for Business" }
    ]
}
"@

(ConvertFrom-Json $json | % tags | % tagName) -Join ", "

# result : O365, Skype for Business
```

Comment: In PowerShell 3+ I find it easier to just use `ForEach-Object` for such things: `ConvertFrom-Json $json | % tags | % tagName`

Comment: @Joey : You are right, Syntax is simpler with %, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly,

```
$separator = ","
$tagname = (ConvertFrom-Json $json).tags.tagName
[String]::Join($separator,$tagname)
```

Or as a one-liner

```
[String]::Join(",",(ConvertFrom-Json $json).tags.tagName)
```